# Is it possible to share a memory table between different PHP sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, memory

For example with MySQL and PHP, when a memory table is created, it will be destroyed at the end of a session, meaning another user can't share and access the same memory table as the previous user.

Any solution for this? (No HTML cache please :))

Comment: Use a normal table instead?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to do? I'm 100% sure there's another way of doing what you're aiming at.

Comment: @Pekka i want to use memory table coz most operations on it are read-onlyl. so i can load it only once to memory.

Comment: @Juhana only my admin module is modifying the table, and all other frontend users are on read-only mode, so i want to speed up things

Comment: "in memory" does not mean, that is in fact _always_ in memory, because at some point (sooner or later) it will get swapped out to the harddisk. You should use a real table instead and for performance consider using a _real_ cache server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL `MEMORY` engine stores data in memory (RAM). It has nothing to do with what PHP process is connected to MySQL. It's MySQL **ENGINE**, therefore - if you connect to MySQL, you have access to data stored in `MEMORY` engine. Once MySQL is rebooted, the data stored in `MEMORY` engine is lost.

On the other hand, there are temporary tables. Temporary tables are session based (based on MySQL session of course, not PHP one). Once the session ends, the table is lost.

Question is - what the heck are you trying to do and why are you constantly confusing naming? Describe what you are aiming for with these past few questions and let more experienced people tell you straight what you need to do.

Comment: am i mistaken between 'temporary table' and 'memory table'?

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a variety of real good solutions to interchange data between scripts - like a text file, a database, an APC, memcache, nosql database.

It is great mystery to me, why there are always people who choose **inappropriate** tool and stubbornly trying to implement it despite of all obstacles and common sense.